Problem with using new command of href inside table
I am trying to create links to a website inside a table.
The website url is long so I tried to create new command that includes the majority of the link. It work well as is but if inside of a table it does not work.
Code & example:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Margins
\topmargin=-0.45in
\evensidemargin=0in
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.0in
\headsep=0.25in

\title{ Title}
\author{ Author }
\date{\today}

% Commands
\newcommand{\linkNep}[1]{\href{https://app.neptune.ai/o/azencot-group/org/foundation-diffusion/runs/details?shortId=#1&type=run}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle  
\pagebreak

% Optional TOC
% \tableofcontents
% \pagebreak

%--Paper--

\linkNep{FOUN-1649}

\section{Baseline}
\subsection{Linear}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
        & test/MSE & train/MSE & Neptune \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 Sines\_205\_819  & 0.060523 & 0.0598502 & \linkNep{FOUN-1649} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}

The compiled latex looks like this:

where the first link is clickable and works well, but the link inside the table does not work well.
edit: complete code was given

Snippets are not good. Always show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Try {\linkNep{FOUN-1649}} in the tabular environment.

Yes! that worked , thank you! @hair-splitter

Unrelated: you should consider using geometry instead of setting those by hand. Some of the settings need to be adjusted against each other and that does nto happen when you set the margins manually like that.

You get several errors, the first one being
! Argument of \href@split has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.24 ...0.060523 & 0.0598502 & \linkNep{FOUN-1649}
                                                   \\

Fix them by enclosing the command in braces.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Commands
\newcommand{\linkNep}[1]{{% one more brace
  \href{https://app.neptune.ai/o/azencot-group/org/%
    foundation-diffusion/runs/details?shortId=#1&type=run}{#1}%
}}

\begin{document}

\linkNep{FOUN-1649}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
 \hline
      & test/MSE & train/MSE & Neptune \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
 Sines\_205\_819  & 0.060523 & 0.0598502 & \linkNep{FOUN-1649} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}


any explanation as to why?

@daleif I guess that \href looks ahead and when it's the final item in a cell, it finds a “forbidden token”, so the message about something missing is issued.

riiight, end of row in tables is a "nasty" business.
